# Unable to add DLL as reference in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I'm unable to add sql compact as reference in Visual Studio 2010 Professional. The project setting is configured to use Target Framework ".NET Framework 3.5". Would anyone know why?

[image: Error message]

Comment: You should add a reference to: System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I cannot add the sqlcecompact35.dll as a reference because it's not a valid CLR assembly.